# R: How to do this matrix operation without loops or more efficient?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying to make this operation matrices, multiplying the first column with 2, 3 and 4, the first hold value, and then multiply the second column with 3 and 4, keep the value of the third and multiply the third column with 4. I want to do this without using a "for" loop, wanted to use functions like sapply or mapply. Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Example with one line:

```
a[1,1]*(a[1,2], a[1,3], a[1,4]) = 2 4 4 4
a[1,1] a[1,2]*(a[1,3], a[1,4]) = 2 4 16 16 #keep a[1,1] a[1,2] 
a[1,1] a[1,2] a[1,3] a[1,3]*(a[1,4]) = 2 4 16 256 # #keep a[1,1] a[1,2] a[1,3]
```

Input:

```
> a<- matrix(2,4,4) # or any else matrix like a<- matrix(c(1,8,10,1,4,1),3,3)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    2    2    2
[2,]    2    2    2    2
[3,]    2    2    2    2
[4,]    2    2    2    2
```

Output:

```
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    4    16    256
[2,]    2    4    16    256
[3,]    2    4    16    256
[4,]    2    4    16    256
```

**EDIT: LOOP VERSION**

```
a<- matrix(2,4,4); 
ai<-a[,1,drop=F]; 
b<- matrix(numeric(0),nrow(a),ncol(a)-1); 

i<- 1; 

for ( i in 1:(ncol(a)-1)){ 

  a<- a[,1]*a[,-1,drop=F]; 
  b[,i]<- a[,1]; 

}

b<- cbind(ai[,1],b); 

b
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what operation you mean; `t(apply(a,1,cumprod))` is what occurred to me, but that doesn't give your output. Can you explain how more clearly how you get from (2,2,2,2) to (2,4,16,256)=(2,2^2,2^4,2^8) ?  What would the output be of `matrix(rep(2:3,8),byrow=TRUE,ncol=4)` ?

Comment: `t(apply(a,1,Reduce,f=\`^\`,accumulate=TRUE))` gives your desired answer, but I'm not sure it's what you really want.

Comment: first I want to multiply the first column with the other, then the second column with the others (3 and 4), keeping the first column, and so successively.

Comment: @Artur_Indio please update your question to include these important details.

Comment: still need more clarification, please. are the operations done within a single row? I suppose "multiply the first column with the other" means "multiply the first two columns" (2*2=4 in each row), but "multiply the second column with the others" means 4*2*2 (=16)? I don't see where the 256 comes from.  Can you write out the precise sequence of arithmetic steps for a single row?

Comment: a[1,1] + a[1,1]*(a[1,2] a[1,3] a[1,4]) = 2 4 4 4
a[1,1] a[1,2] + a[1,2]*(a[1,3] a[1,4]) = 2 4 16 16
a[1,1] a[1,2] a[1,3] + a[1,3]*(a[1,4]) = 2 4 16 256

Comment: Much better.  I don't have time to work on this now, but I think the only way to do this without loops (non-recursively) will be to write out the expression and see that it is essentially `{a1,a1*a2,a1^2*a2*a3,a1^4*a2^2*a3*a4}`, and work out an R expression for evaluating this.  Then `apply` it to every row.

Comment: @ssdecontrol - that's not overly helpful. `Reduce` has been mentioned above already. If you have a straightforward solution using `Reduce`, please share it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see it mentioned. @BenBolker's answer with `Reduce` is what I had in mind, but it seems like OP isn't clear about what he wants.

Comment: Now is a little clearer with my editions? It's hard to explain this problem, sorry.

Comment: I put the loop version. @MrFlick could look this question, please.

Comment: It seems like something like `b <- cbind(a[, 1], sapply(2:ncol(a), function(x)  a[, x] <<- a[, x - 1]^2))` could work, but I'm still not sure what you actually doing here

Comment: @DavidArenburg I put a figure explaining the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is, starting with a matrix A with N columns, perform the following steps:

Step 1. Multiply columns 2 through N of A by column 1 of A. Call the resulting matrix A1.

Step 2. Multiply columns 3 through N of A1 by column 2 of A1. Call the resulting matrix A2.

...

Step (N-1). Multiply column N of A(N-2) by column (N-1) of A(N-2). This is the desired result.

If this is indeed what you are trying to do, you need to either write a double `for` loop (which you want to avoid, as you say) or come up with some iterative method of performing the above steps.

The double `for` way would look something like this

```
DoubleFor <- function(m) {
    res <- m
    for(i in 1:(ncol(res)-1)) {
        for(j in (i+1):ncol(res)) {
            res[, j] <- res[, i] * res[, j]
        }
    }
    res
}
```

Using R's vectorized operations, you can avoid the inner `for` loop

```
SingleFor <- function(m) {
    res <- m
    for(i in 1:(ncol(res)-1)) 
        res[, (i+1):ncol(res)] <- res[, i] * res[, (i+1):ncol(res)]
    res
}
```

When it comes to iterating a procedure, you may want to define a recursive function, or use `Reduce`. The recursive function would be something like

```
RecursiveFun <- function(m, i = 1) {
    if (i == ncol(m)) return(m)
    n <- ncol(m)
    m[, (i+1):n] <- m[, (i+1):n] * m[, i]
    Recall(m, i + 1) # Thanks to @batiste for suggesting using Recall()!
}
```

while `Reduce` would use a similar function without the recursion (which is provided by `Reduce`)

```
ReduceFun <- function(m) { 
    Reduce(function(i, m) {
            n <- ncol(m)
            m[, (i+1):n] <- m[, (i+1):n] * m[, i]
            m
        }, c((ncol(m)-1):1, list(m)), right = T)
}
```

These will all produce the same result, e.g. testing on your matrix

```
a <- matrix(c(1, 8, 10, 1, 4, 1), 3, 3)
DoubleFor(a)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    8   32 2048
# [3,]   10   10 1000
all(DoubleFor(a) == SingleFor(a) & SingleFor(a) == RecursiveFun(a) & 
    RecursiveFun(a) == ReduceFun(a))
# [1] TRUE
```

Just out of curiosity, I did a quick speed comparison, but I don't think any one of the above will be significantly faster than the others for your size of matrices, so I would just go with the one you think is more readable.

```
a <- matrix(rnorm(1e6),  ncol = 1e3)
system.time(DoubleFor(a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  22.158   0.012  22.220 
system.time(SingleFor(a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  27.349   0.004  27.415 
system.time(RecursiveFun(a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  25.150   1.336  26.534 
system.time(ReduceFun(a))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  26.574   0.004  26.626
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much! This is exactly that I looking for. I'm was trying to do this for educational purposes, same with no significantly faster is much important to me these recursive functions, thanks again!

Comment: i think `Recall` is advised for recursive functions

Comment: @baptiste Thanks, I did not know about `Recall`! Very useful tip, will update the answer.